# redirect using javascript without flash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to do the following:

I want to redirect to another page using javascript, but I want the page (that we redirect to) to fade in instead of being redirect to aggressively. How can Iget that done using jquery?

I tried the following:

```
$('.splash').hide();

$('.splash').fadeIn(2000,
      function() {
            setTimeout(
                  function() {
                        document.location.href = 'test.html';
                  },100)

<div class = "splash"></div>
```

Comment: IE supports (very non-standard) [interpage transitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx#Interpage_Transition).

Answer (score 1):

Well you could `$('html').fadeOut();` the current page you are on, then do your redirect. But that second page would have to have it's own `$('html').fadeIn();`

There is no way to push a jQuery execution onto a totally separate page unfortunately :/

You could try loading the page with `$.load()` AJAX style also.

Comment: Loading the data (as data with type:text) and then removing all the content from the body, adding this new data to body, setting its opacity to 0 and then fading it in might work as intended. I'm not sure about performance, though.

Comment: As an example of the first approach, http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/